# separating a field containing commas

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, behance-api

Using handlebars.js and the Behance API - `{{user.sections.[availability]}}` outputs - `Full-Time, Contract, Relocation`.

I would like to have each comma separated word output as its item, similar to the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>Full-Time</li>
  <li>Contract</li>
  <li>Relocation</li>
</ul>
```

Would this include some Javascript or #each statement? If so could someone guide me toward a solution or snippet that will help?

---

For those asking ... here is my current javascript code, and HTML.

```
(function() {
    var behanceUserAPI = 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/' + userID + '?callback=?&api_key=' + apiKey;
    function setUserTemplate() {
        var userData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')),
            getTemplate = $('#user').html(),
            template = Handlebars.compile(getTemplate),
            result = template(userData);
        $('body').html(result);
        // AUTO-TIME GREETING + COPYRIGHT -----------------------------------------
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.getHours();
        var greeting = "";
        if (time < 12) {
            greeting = "Morning";
        } else if ((time >= 12) && (time < 19)) {
            greeting = "Howdy";
        } else {
            greeting = "Evening";
        }
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = greeting;
        document.getElementById("auto-year").innerHTML = "Copyright &copy; " + date.getFullYear();
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')) {
        setUserTemplate();
    } else {
        $.getJSON(behanceUserAPI, function(user) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(user);
            sessionStorage.setItem('behanceUser', data);
            setUserTemplate();
        });
    }
})();

<ul class="availability">
  {{#splitSTring user.sections.[Availability] delimiter=", "}}
    <li><i class="icon-check twentytwo color"></i><span>{{this}}</span>   </li>
  {{/splitString}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing to be in context of actual question:

You're going to want to take the field and turn it into an array. So something like

```
var availabilities = user.sections.availability.split(',');

//send availabilities to template
```

Then in your template you can print it out as:

```
{{#each availabilities as |time|}}
  <li>{{time}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Or as @isherwood suggests you can register a HandleBars helper to do this for you.

Comment: if the template is evaluating it like `user.sections.availability.toString()` and all the items in the array are strings, there is a chance that it would print out as 'item1, item2, item3'.

Comment: Sorry, but if you read the whole question w/ title in context then yes I should have been more aware that it was a string field.

Comment: It is not an array ... it is just text in a text field. So I would need a code that would read the text and separate each item based on the comma. I think ...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split could do it I think. Just depends on if you want to do the split in the controller or at the template level.

Answer (score 1):

Register a helper and specify the comma-space as a delimiter.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("splitString", function(options){
      var ret = "";

      var tempArr = context.trim().split(options.hash["delimiter"]);

      for(var i=0; i < tempArr.length; i++)
      {
        ret = ret + options.fn(tempArr[i]);
      }

      return ret;
});


<ul>
  {{#splitSTring user.sections.[availability] delimiter=", "}}
  <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/splitString}}
</ul>
```

**[More](http://www.kamalpreetsingh.com/78/handlebars-split-strings-helper/)**

Note that this is an incomplete example. I've attempted to translate it to your code, but I don't have it all. I suggest starting with the linked example instead.

Comment: I added my current code to my original post. I tried what you said but still did not work. I think now I am just not sure where and how to integrate your snippet into my code.

Comment: Any update now that have included my full code? I tried your "more" link and I was able to get it to work, however I had to disable part of the code, so I was not sure how to combine it all together, so your code, works with my code.